# how use properties from Directory.Build.props in Import from project file of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have this situation:

I have a .proj file in project directory:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="PQExtensionTest.pq">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Content Include="PQExtensionTest.query.pq">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- <Import Project="..\Directory.Build.props" /> -->
  <Import Project="$(aProperty)add.targets" />
</Project>
```

In the solution directory (..\ from project directory) I have file Directory.Build.props:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="BuildExtension" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <aProperty>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/Subdir/</aProperty>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

In the project directory I have subdirectory "Subdir", where there is file add.targets, which contains all the targets I need (do not show it's contains here because it is not relevant to the problem).

So all above has this folder structure:

```
Solution directory
  Directory.Build.props
  Project Directory
    Project.mproj
    Subdir
      add.targets
```

Preparing all the above, I expected that aProperty will be initiated before the import and the import of add.targets will happen without problem. But I get error that imported project is not found, and I see in error message that MSBuild tries to import from project directory, and not from subdirectory Subdir.

If I uncomment this row:

```
<Import Project="..\Directory.Build.props" />
```

all works fine.

The only reasonable explanation for me of such behavior is that aProperty is empty at the moment of importing, because explicit import happens before implicit one.

Is there any way to force MSBuild to inexplicitly import Directory.Build.props before any other imports, while work in Visual Studio?

Comment: Hi Andrey, what do you mean "If I use Prop in Target, all works fine."? Use the target in proj file? And what's the Prop?Could you share your sample proj file and content of Directory.Build.props here. So that I can check it directly.

Comment: Hi @LanceLi-MSFT! Thanks for your response. I corrected my initial post above. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I've checked your update. And perhaps you've read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017). The Directory.Build.Targets file can work before any other imports while work in Visual Studio, this is the advantage of it. Also, the way of using can be implicitly, but this feature only support for C# and VB project.

Comment: I have written it as details below, hope it helps solve your puzzle. And since the feature(Directory.Build.props) now only supports C# and Vb, I'm afraid it can't satisfy your needs if you don't use .net. And if my answer is helpful for solving your puzzle, please mark it as answer. Also, any update or further question feel free to contact me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### "While in Visual Studio"

> For C# and VB language project, we don't need to import
>   Directory.Build.props manually or force it before other imports.

When creating a new project(C# or VB) in VS, open its proj file we can find the format is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Every time when creating new C# or VB project, the top line within the `<Project>`node is `Import project="Microsoft.Common.props"`, and we can find the sentence from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets):

When MSBuild runs, `Microsoft.Common.props` searches your directory structure for the `Directory.Build.props` file (and `Microsoft.Common.targets looks for Directory.Build.targets`). **If it finds one, it imports the property.**

So in visual studio, we don't need to force it before other imports.Its always called after `import Microsoft.Common.props`, and since the `import Microsoft.Common.props` is always first line of project node by default, the Directory.Build.Targets is always implicitly imported right after the Microsoft.Common.props and before others.

Note: This feature only supports C# and VB, cause only these two kinds of projects will import the Microsoft.Common.Props in proj file.

> And for other kinds of projects, just like your .mproj or
>   .vcxproj(C++), this feature(Directory.Build.props) is not supported
>   yet.

So the Directory.Build.Targets or .props is the same as any custom .props. It doesn't make difference between Directory.Build.Targets and anyName.props.

In this way,to read the value in it we have to use `import project` to call it manually. **And that's why the build can't succeed until you uncomment the row**:`<Import Project="..\Directory.Build.props" />`

Comment: Lance Li-MSFT, yes, I read the article you mentioned, and noticed that Directory.Build.* features are for C# and VB. But I wanted to try whether it works for my type of projects :-). And I have to say that both Directory.Build.* features work _in someway_ for my project. Sorry I didn't mentioned it in my updated info. How it works for a Directory.Build.props: if place Directory.Build.props in an upper folder, and use aProperty in a Task (e.g. Message) of imported project, I can see the actual (non-empty) value of aProperty in the text which Message produces.

Comment: And Directory.Build.targets works either, but it is called earlier than any Targets from imported projects are called, so you cannot re-define targets or properties of what is define in the project. So while MSBuild actually uses both features for my project (it is Power Query SDK, by the way), it calls them at the moments (in order) which actually doesn't provide any value. That was my question.

Comment: Again - the problem is not because the features doesn't work at all for non-CS/VB projects. They work, and in some scenarios they can be useful - but I'd like them to work in another order and would be glad to understand is it possible to change that order in someway.

Comment: The order is controlled by the order of <Import> tag in proj file. Like the example you use, if uncomment the row, it works fine. And if exchange the order of the two imports after uncomment the row like import add.targets first, import directory.build.prop second, the build will fail again.

Comment: Since the feature works in some scenarios of yours, import your custom add.targets below where import or call the Directory.Build.Props may help.

Comment: I understand that workaround (since I put it in my question code :-)), there is a number of ways how to resolve that, but my question is "Is there any way to force MSBuild to inexplicitly import Directory.Build.props **before** any other imports, while work in Visual Studio?" I can use Directory.Build.props inexplicitly in Targets, but it would be great to use it for "set up" imports as well.

Comment: If what you mean is an option or settings in Tools=>options or Project=>properties, I'm afraid we don't have this option for current vs versions. Sorry for this inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

The way to import properties from 'Directory.Build.props' file from nested folder structure is given below:

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019

Note that:
1. These property file definition works from MSBuild tools version 15.0
2. You need to be aware of where to place this import: At the beginning of the file or at the end of the file. Generally it is good to place at the end as nested properties will be visible to parent properties.