# How to override the solution-wide `CodeAnalysisRuleSet` in .NET 4.8 project file?

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

Running VS2022.

I have setup a `PropertyGroup` to configure the `CodeAnalysisRuleSet` for the solution in a `Directory.Build.props` file which is located next to my solution.
The solution has a mix of `netcoreapp3.1` `netstandard2.0` and `net48``v4.8` targeted projects.

The idea is to enable strict analysis solution-wide and allow more lax analysis on a per-project basis.

For `netcoreapp3.1` and `netstandard2.0` projects, this works exactly as expected -- add a `CodeAnalysisRuleSet` pointing at the lax ruleset to the csproj file.

For the .NET 4.8 projects I expected the same approach to work, but no luck.

So, I went the GUI approach via Project Properties > Code Analysis and selecting the lax ruleset from the dropdown. After saving the project I can visually verify the correct `CodeAnalysisRuleSet` has been added to the XML in the csproj file for each build configuration `PropertyGroup`. The file looks exactly how it did when I configured the csproj file directly.

However, when I close and re-open the project the strict ruleset from `Directory.Build.props` is selected in the Code Analysis tab -- not the value that is configured in the csproj file.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Could you please share the specific configuration on your side if possible? On my side, configuration in Directory.Build.props doesn't affect project level properties on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compared against a working project file, and the only major difference was this line was missing from the non-working project files:

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />`

Fix is to add that line in as the first child of `<Project>` as such:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213216/how-use-properties-from-directory-build-props-in-import-from-project-file-of-vis) gives a pretty good picture of what happens when you omit this line.

Answer (score 0):

There may be several things at play here.

It is a good practice to test if a property is already set before setting its value - see [MSBuild best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-best-practices?view=vs-2022). But the definitions of `CodeAnalysisRuleSet` in the project templates don't check. i.e. in the .csproj you have

```xml
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>RuleSetPathAndName</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
```

The `Directory.Build.props` file is imported early. Any value for `CodeAnalysisRuleSet` set in the `Directory.Build.props` file will be overwritten by the project.

It sounds like this is the behavior you intend: a 'global' default ruleset for projects that don't define `CodeAnalysisRuleSet`.

The Visual Studio IDE, for reasons of responsiveness and performance, is sometimes 'too clever'. The ruleset shown in the GUI may be a false display and/or may be a cache issue.

Some steps to try:

1. Close Visual Studio completely.
2. Verify that your source files, `Directory.Build.props` and the .csproj files, have the correct settings.
3. With VS2022, there will be a `.vs` folder in the solution folder. This is the Visual Studio cache. (Note the `.vs` folder should never be version controlled.) Delete the `.vs` folder. Visual Studio will rebuild it the next time the solution is opened.
4. In a dev prompt run a command line build of your solution. Verify if the correct rule sets are used. If the CLI build doesn't behave as expected, there may be an issue in the MSBuild code.
5. Open Visual Studio and open the solution in Visual Studio. Run a build and verify if the correct rule sets are used. The VS build and CLI build should match in terms of the rulesets used.
6. Finally check the project properties in the UI. If the UI is now showing the correct value, the issue may have been a corrupted cache.